# How to use std::vector.insert()?

Tags: c++, stdvector

So, I'm trying to learn how to use `std::vectors`, but I have a problem:

```
std::vector<Box>entities;

entities.insert(1, Box(&world, b2Vec2(Camera.getCenter().x, Camera.getCenter().y), b2Vec2(25, 25), 0, sf::Color::Red, b2_dynamicBody, 1.0f, 0.3));
```

How come that doesn't work? It gives me the following error :

```
Error no instace of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _alloc>::insert [with _Ty=Box, _Alloc=std::allocator<Box>] matches the argument list. Argument types are (int, Box). Object type is std::vector<Box, std::allocator<Box>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe [read some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) first?

Comment: Isn't this more to do with `Box` and less to do with `vector`? Can you do anything with a `std::vector<int>` for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter should be an iterator, not an index. You can get an iterator to position 1 by using `entities.begin() + 1`.

Note that position 1 is the location of the *second* element in the vector: vector indexing is *zero-based*.

Comment: How would I access a function inside the box class?

Comment: @BiiX Don't be lazy. Look it up. Or pay someone to write your code for you.

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't even know how to look it up since I don't know good enough English.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is wrong. You should specify an **iterator**, not an index.

```
entities.insert(entities.begin() + i, theItem);
```

where `i` is the position you want to insert at. Note that the vector must be at least of size `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`entities.insert(entities.begin(), /*other stuff as before*/` would insert at the beginning of your vector. (i.e. the *zeroth* element). Remember that `vector` indexing is zero-based.

`entities.insert(1 + entities.begin(), /*other stuff as before*/` would insert at the *second* spot.

Answer (score 1):

All overloaded versions of the method `insert` require that the first argument would be of type `std::vector<Box>::const_iterator` applied to your vector definition. This iterator specifies the position where a new element must be inserted.

However you are passing in an integer value 1 instead of the iterator

```
entities.insert(1, 
               ^^^
                Box(&world, b2Vec2(Camera.getCenter().x, Camera.getCenter().y),
                    b2Vec2(25, 25), 0, sf::Color::Red, b2_dynamicBody, 1.0f, 0.3));
```

There is no implicit conversion from an object of type `int` to an object of type `std::vector<Box>::const_iterator`. So the compiler issues an error.

Maybe you mean the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

//...

entities.insert( std::next( entities.begin() ), 
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                Box(&world, b2Vec2(Camera.getCenter().x, Camera.getCenter().y),
                    b2Vec2(25, 25), 0, sf::Color::Red, b2_dynamicBody, 1.0f, 0.3));
```

Or if your compiler does not support function `std::next` then you can jjust write

```
entities.insert( entities.begin() + 1, 
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                Box(&world, b2Vec2(Camera.getCenter().x, Camera.getCenter().y),
                    b2Vec2(25, 25), 0, sf::Color::Red, b2_dynamicBody, 1.0f, 0.3));
```